# Django is not seeing my MySQLdb module on CentOS 7 with mysqlclient installed and database working

Tags: python, mysql, django, linux, python-3.x

I've seen many posts telling what is likely the problem, but I've been down each road.  I have a database server and want to create a Django website to connect to it.  I use mysql5.6 on the server, installed the community edition on both client and server.
I followed the instructions on the django site: tested mysql, tested that django is installed, tested its version in python (2.0.3), tested python version (3.6), test connection to server from client with specified user to test database (ok, can select data at mysql> prompt).  as root, have done pip install mysqlclient, have done yum install mysql-community-client, etc.
I get to this point:

> $ cd /my/site/directory
>
> $ python manage.py newserver

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.3 py3.6.egg/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
>    import MySQLdb as Database
>  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
>import _mysql
>ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__mysql)

>The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
>    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.3-py3.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in >execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
>  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.3-py3.6.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
>  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.3-py3.6.egg/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
>  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.3-py3.6.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
>  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.3-py3.6.egg/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
>  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
>  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
>  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
>  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
>  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
>  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.3-py3.6.egg/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
>  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.3-py3.6.egg/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
>  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.3-py3.6.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 114, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
>  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.3-py3.6.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 315, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
>  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.3-py3.6.egg/django/db/models/options.py", line 205, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
>  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.3-py3.6.egg/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
>  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.3-py3.6.egg/django/db/utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
>  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.3-py3.6.egg/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
>  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Django-2.0.3-py3.6.egg/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    ) from err
>django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
>Did you install mysqlclient?
```

I'm about to surrender and go old school with PHP but really would like to use something like Django.  All help appreciated!

Here is the MySQL output from client (CentOS 7.4) to server (CentOS 7.4 also):

```
>Enter password: 
>Reading table information for completion of table and column names
>You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A>

>Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
>Your MySQL connection id is 25
>Server version: 5.6.39 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

>Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

>Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
>affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
>owners.

>Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

>MySQL> select * from test;
>+------+----------+
>| fn   | ln       |
>+------+----------+
>| Joe  | DiMaggio |
>+------+----------+
>1 row in set (0.01 sec)

Here is output from django:
>[user@build hdrn]$ python -m django --version
>2.0.3

Here is output from python
$ python
>Python 3.6.4 (default, Mar 27 2018, 14:37:57) 
>[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux
>Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 

Here is uname from client machine:
>Linux build.mynetwork.com 3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64.debug #1 SMP Thu Jan 4 01:24:54 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

-------------- end of question ------------------

Comment: Why are you writing: "python manage.py newserver" . It should be "python manage.py runserver"

Comment: My mistake: I typed: "python manage.py runserver".  (not "newserver")

Comment: Can you please post your settings.py file? and your requirements file please? .... If you do a: pip freeze > requirements.txt   .... then you'll have a requirements.txt file which has the current packages that have been installed